# Найти крестовину на фотографии и определить ее местоположение

Tags: python, opencv

Всех приветствую. Имеется такая фотография, нужно найти на ней эту крестовину и определить ее местоположение (x, y)

Изображение:

[image: исходник]

То, что мне нужно:

[image: готовое изображение]

То, что я уже пробовал (и это работает очень криво):

```
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        (contours, _) = cv2.findContours(result, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        for rect in contours:
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(rect)

            rect = cv2.minAreaRect(rect)  
            box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)  
            box = np.int0(box)  
            cv2.drawContours(result, [box], 0, (255, 0, 0), 2) 

            print(x, y)

        cv2.imshow('1', result)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import cv2

file = "4qUkj.jpg"
template_file = "template.png"
image = cv2.imread(file)
template = cv2.imread(template_file)
res = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)
(_min_val, _max_val, min_loc, _max_loc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

print(min_loc)
# (141, 13)
```

matchtemplate предельно подходит вам. Несколько очевидных вещей: он ищет участок на image, который наиболее похож на шаблон (template).[image: template.png]